# Add data to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have manage to get the information I need from a website. Now I want to insert the data into an array, so I can easily insert the information to the database.

Here's how the code looks like right now:

```
<?php

    $page = file_get_contents("http://www.kalender.se/helgdagar");
    $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $page));
    $string = preg_replace("#<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>#s", '|\1', $string);
    preg_match_all("/<td>([\d-]{10})<\/td><td>(.*?)<\/td>/s", $string, $matches);

    foreach($matches[0] AS $test) {
        $splitted = explode('|', $test);
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($splitted[0]); echo '</pre>';
    }

?>
```

Which prints out the following with `$splitted[0]`:

```
2018-01-01
2018-01-06
2018-03-30
2018-04-01
2018-04-02
2018-05-01
2018-05-10
2018-05-20
2018-06-06
2018-06-23
2018-11-03
2018-12-25
2018-12-26
```

And with `$splitted[1]`:

```
Nyårsdagen
Trettondedag jul
Långfredagen
Påskdagen
Annandag påsk
Första maj
Kristi himmelfärdsdag
Pingstdagen
Sveriges nationaldag
Midsommar
Alla helgons dag
Juldagen
Annandag jul
```

I want this information to be grouped and also be in an array, like this:

```
Array(
    '2018-01-01' => 'Nyårsdagen',
    '2018-01-06' => 'Trettondedag jul',
    ... and so on
);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't even know that `array_combine()` even existed until Jon Stirling mentioned it in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177165/add-data-to-an-array#comment85359609_49177165). Many thanks, Jon! :)

Here's the final result:

```
<?php

    $page = file_get_contents("http://www.kalender.se/helgdagar");
    $string = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $page));
    $string = preg_replace("#<a.*?>(.*?)<\/a>#s", '\1', $string);
    preg_match_all("/<td>([\d-]{10})<\/td><td>(.*?)<\/td>/s", $string, $matches);

    $array_test_1 = Array();
    foreach($matches[1] AS $test1) {
        $array_test_1[] = $test1;
        # echo '<pre>'; print_r($splitted[1]); echo '</pre>';
    }

    $array_test_2 = Array();
    foreach($matches[2] AS $test2) {
        $array_test_2[] = $test2;
        # echo '<pre>'; print_r($splitted[1]); echo '</pre>';
    }

    $finishit = array_combine($array_test_1, $array_test_2);

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($finishit); echo '</pre>';

?>
```